# How to use replace characters in excel?

Tags: excel, replace

I'm having trouble trying to use replace characters in MS excel. Help says `*` and `?` can both replace characters, but if I try using them in `IF`, I don't get correct results.
For example:

```
A1="something"
=IF(A1="*mething";"yes";"no")
```

I always get `no`... How to use `*` correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wildcards don't work with comparison operators like =

To achieve what you want you can use COUNTIF which does accept wildcards, i.e.

`=IF(COUNTIF(A1;"*mething")>0;"yes";"no")`

or RIGHT function like

`=IF(RIGHT(A1;7)="mething";"yes";"no")`

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards cannot be used in this context.  Use something like:

**=IF(ISERROR(FIND("mething",A1)),"No","Yes")**